# How to build React Wizard with dynamic number of steps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am building a wizard based on React, Redux and React Router V4.

When the widget get mounted, I fetch questions from an API. All these questions should be one step in the wizard. I never know, how much steps the wizard will have.

At the beginning is a welcome-step and at the end the user sees a thank-you website.

Building a wizard with a fixed number of steps would be easy. I am sure building the wizard with dynamic number of steps is easy too, when you know how to.

Where should I put the logic to A) get the next/previous step/route and B) navigate to it?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this library: [react-albus](https://github.com/americanexpress/react-albus)

Comment: Were you able to come up with anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a container component for your wizard and have it render step components based on props. 
The logic would go in a separate file which would be imported into the container.

I would recommend using either [redux-form](http://www.redux-form.com) or some other alternative to manage your form state in this scenario.